# Stickies App Stopped Remembering Note Position

Tags: macos

I'm in OSX 10.10.2 and like to use Stickies (as a quick text dump before moving on). I have perhaps 100 notes and everything was fine until recently when the app stopped remembering the position I had dragged a note to.

I tried removing a fair number of notes but the problem still persists - drag a note, switch app and come back, the note is back where it started. Restarting doesn't help.

I can't see any other issues with the app.

Is there anything I can try before rage-quitting and switching to real post-it notes?

Comment: And before, they did remember their positions? And are you using a Macbook? And do you have an external screen?

Comment: thx Bro, this is on an iMac, no external screen and only in one "Space"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Quit Stickies
2. Open a Finder window
3. Navigate to `~/Library/Saved Application States/`
4. Look for `com.apple.Stickies.savedState` and Trash it
5. Relaunch Stickies

Hopefully that helps. :)

NOTE: This will reset the positions of ALL your current Stickies.

Comment: Thx @Stuart I rly appreciate yr help but I had a problem. If the app is closed, the com.apple.Stickies folder disappears from Saved States. If I trash it while app is open, it doesnt fix the issue. If I try to empty trash while app open, I get msg "The operation can’t be completed because the item “data.data” is in use." So I'm thinking it still uses the file from the trash? What shd I do?

Comment: Are you sure it disappears and doesn't just get overwritten and displayed at the bottom of the file list? It should remain in that folder so that window state can be restored on next launch. This is assuming you have "Restore Window State" enabled in System Preferences > General, of course.

Comment: I ended up doing a `sudo rm -R` on the saved state in Trash, that seemed to do the trick. There was something weird going on, I wish I screencap'd it, but it's all good now! Thx again Stu you're a legend!